# Did server successfully receive request

Tags: standards, connection-timeout, offline-mode

I am working on a `C# mobile` application that requires major interaction with a `PHP` web server. However, the application also needs to support an "offline mode" as connection will be over a `cellular network`. This network may drop requests at random times. The problem that I have experienced with previous "Offline Mode" applications is that when a request results in a Timeout, the server may or may not have already processed that request. In cases where sending the request more than once would create a duplicate, this is a problem. I was walking through this and came up with the following idea.

- Mobile sets a header value such as `UniqueRequestID: 1` to be sent with the request.
- Upon receiving the request, the PHP server adds the `UniqueRequestID` to the current user session `$_SESSION['RequestID'][] = $headers['UniqueRequestID'];`
- Server implements a GetRequestByID that returns true if the `id` exists for the current session or false if not. Alternatively, this could returned the cached result of the request.

This seems to be a somewhat reliable way of seeing if a request successfully contacted the server. In mobile, upon re-connecting to the server, we check if the request was received. If so, skip that pending `offline message` and go to the next one.

**Question**
Have I reinvented the wheel here? Is this method prone to failure (or am I going down a rabbit hole)? Is there a better way / alternative?

-*I was pitching this to other developers here and we thought that this seemed very simple implying that this "system" would likely already exist somewhere.*

-*Apologies if my Google skills are failing me today.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you correctly stated, this problem is not new. There have been multiple attempts to solve it at different levels.

**Transport level**

HTTP transport protocol itself does not provide any mechanisms for reliable data transfer. One of the reasons is that HTTP is stateless and don't care much about previous requests and responses. There have been attempts by IBM to make a reliable transport protocol called HTTPR what was based on HTTP, but it never got popular. You can read more about it [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-httprspec/).

**Messaging level**

Most Web Services out there still uses HTTP as a transport protocol and SOAP messaging protocol on top of it. SOAP over HTTP is not sufficient when an application-level messaging protocol must also guarantee some level of reliability and security. This is why `WS-Reliability` and `WS-ReliableMessaging` protocols where introduced. Those protocols allow SOAP messages to be reliably delivered between distributed applications in the presence of software component, system, or network failures. At the same time they provide additional security. You can read more about those protocols [here](http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsrm/ws-reliability/v1.1/wsrm-ws_reliability-1.1-spec-os.pdf) and [here](http://specs.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/rm/ws-reliablemessaging.pdf).

**Your solution**

I guess there is nothing wrong with your approach if you need a simple way to ensure that message has not been already processed. I would recommend to use database instead of session to store processing result for each request. If you use `$_SESSION['RequestID'][]` you will run in to trouble if the session is lost (user is offline for specific time, server is restarted or has crashed, etc). Also, if you use database instead of session, you can scale-up easier later on just by adding extra web server.

Comment: I actually thought about the database thing first. I thought a session based system would keep the rabbit hole from going to deep. IE Database means we need to set up a cleanup script or manage a separate server. I feel with the session thing, we would resolve 90% of the problem with 10% of the work if we implemented it in a session first. Perhaps we could switch / scale up to a database later if we find the expired session thing becomes a real issue. The transport level & messaging level stuff would (I think) be a bit of overkill here, but it is very good information to have.

Comment: To add to your answer, reading through the ReliableMessaging documentation suggests that we don't really need to look for message acknowledgement, but instead, the application logic should handle these situations. http://www.infoq.com/articles/no-reliable-messaging